# Trying to use openGL in vscode

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw-w64

I tried to use vscode to make an opengl application.

i ran mingw32-make in the terminal and got this error:

```
g++ -g --std=c++17 -I../include -L../lib ../src/*.cpp ../src/glad.c -lglfw3dll -o main 
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: ../src/*.cpp: Invalid argument
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

[here is the github rep](https://github.com/lunox2004/physics-engine) if anyone wants to look further/

Comment: Maybe `../src` does not exist. Looking at the repo its odd you don't want to build `main.cpp` especially since your executable is name `main` and that there are no `.cpp` files in the `src` folder.

Comment: Are you really using a Makefile? It does not appear a Makefile is used. Also this does not look like VSCode is involved in the building.

Comment: The problem is that there are no files that match the expression `../src/*.cpp`.  When there are no files matching an expression, the shell will just pass through the expression itself, unaltered.  When the compiler sees that expression `../src/*.cpp` it tries to compile it, but of course that doesn't work and you get this error.